# How to speed up process when apply a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, scipy

I have a function peak_value which takes two iuputs area and data and returns a new column in data with potential peaks as output. I actually want to apply this peak value function on list of dataframes e.g data = [df1, df2, df3...dfn2] each dataframe has respective value of area e.g area = [a1, a2, a3.....an]. I have applied argrelextrema function to speed up the processing but not succeed so far. Is there any way to make it fast?

```
def peak_value(data,area):
    lag = np.round(5 + np.log10(area))

    data_tmp = data.loc[data['loc_max']==1]  


    data_sorted = data_tmp.sort_values(by='value',ascending=False) 
    data_sorted['idx'] = data_sorted.index  
    data_sorted = data_sorted.reset_index(drop = True) 

    flag = 0
    i = 0

    updated = len(data_sorted)

    while i < updated and flag == 0:
        lag_pre = np.arange(data_sorted['date'][i]-lag,data_sorted['date'][i])
        lag_post = np.arange(data_sorted['date'][i]+1,data_sorted['date'][i]+lag+1)
        lag_interval = np.concatenate((lag_pre,lag_post))
        ind_del = data_sorted.iloc[np.isin(data_sorted['date'],lag_interval)].index
        data_sorted = data_sorted.drop(data_sorted.index[ind_del])
        data_sorted = data_sorted.reset_index(drop=True)
        updated = len(data_sorted)
        if i < updated:
            flag = 0
        else:
            flag = 1

        i = i+1

    #adds a column that says which are the potential peaks

    data['Potential_peaks'] = np.zeros(len(data))
    data['Potential_peaks'].loc[data_sorted['idx']] = 1               
    return data 


def max_new(data):
    loc_opt_ind = argrelextrema(df, np.greater)
    Potential_peaks = np.zeros(len(data))
    Potential_peaks[loc_opt_ind] = 1
    data['Potential_peaks']= Potential_peaks
    return data

new_max= []
for index, df in enumerate(data):  
    max_values = max_new(df).Potential_peaks
    new_max.append(max_values)
```

Comment: The answer to the question as asked is "yes". Please provide an MCVE as defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Make sure it's actually minimal. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

If it's possible to run your solution in parallel, then I think [Joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a viable solution.

I tried it myself and I like it a lot. The amount of modifications needed for this to work is really low.

Here's an example about how it work:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

numbers = list(range(10))

def square(x):
    return x ** 2
result = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(square)(number) for number in numbers)

print(result) # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

If this solution doesn't work for you, please share some more details about your problems.

Comment: This is a comment asking for clarification, not a valid answer. Please post it as such

Comment: Why so? I already provide a solution based on the information in the question. That's Joblib

Comment: There is no meaningful information in the question within the scope of SO. Asking for libraries is off topic. Unless you can show how to use joblib to solve OP's problem rather than just throw the name out there, I posit that this is a comment.